# Tkinter Python printing user input

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to take each variable and use it but I'm not sure how print out the result of the outputs. Can someone give me some advice? I'm new with tkinter. Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import *

class MyDialog(simpledialog.Dialog):

    def body(self, master):

        Label(master, text="First:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Second:").grid(row=1)
        Label(master, text="Third:").grid(row=2)
        Label(master, text="Fourth:").grid(row=3)

        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e2 = Entry(master)
        self.e3 = Entry(master)
        self.e4 = Entry(master)

        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.e4.grid(row=3, column=1)

        return self.e1 # initial focus

    def apply(self):
        first = self.e1.get()
        second = self.e2.get()
        third = self.e3.get()
        fourth =  self.e4.get()


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
d = MyDialog(root)
print (root)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `self.result` inside `apply()`:

```
def apply(self):
    first = self.e1.get()
    second = self.e2.get()
    third = self.e3.get()
    fourth =  self.e4.get()
    self.result = (first, second, third, fourth)
```

Then you can get the result using `d.result`:

```py
d = MyDialog(root)
print(d.result)
```